# German umlaut in debezium server

Tags: sql-server, azure-eventhub, debezium

I am using *debezium-server* to stream changes from *ms sql server* to Azure event hubs.
However German umlauts like Ü are send as ��.

I have tried to format the text columns in sql server to **utf8** and **latin1** but the result remains the same.

Comment: If this were a SQL Server collation issue then the `Ü` (U+00DC) would get stored as `?` or `??` (actual ASCII question mark characters), but since you're seeing Missing Glyph characters �� this seems to be a configuration issue in Debezium.

Comment: Don't get me wrong although it was a nice hint it did not really resolve the question. Once I found a solution I can post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed by starting up the Debezium Dockerfile using:

```yaml
environment:
  JAVA_OPTS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

which is effectively a java environment variable.

Tested on Debezium 1.7.1.Final.